# getView from overloaded ArrayAdapter is not beeing called from AsyncTask / onPostExecute

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, android-arrayadapter

Hi its my first post here nad my first a little bit more advanced app for my Android phone... I know that this subject was mentioned here, google knows many examples, however they are not exacty what im looking form ;(

I admit I'm a n00000b... in terms of Android coding... I started... ust few days ago, please forgive me :)

The problem is that my listview element is not beeing populated. App compiles and runs without errors, BUT it doesnt lunch getView. From what i have read on the web... I need this to display my beloved listview with its content...

Please help :)

```
    package com.test.stackParser;

    public class StackParserActivity extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
private ProgressDialog pd;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    //final TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    //tv.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());

    Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    button.setOnClickListener(myListener);
}

private OnClickListener myListener = new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        pd = ProgressDialog.show(StackParserActivity.this, "Working...", "request to server", true, false);
        new ParseSite().execute("http://multikino.pl/pl/repertuar/warszawa-ursynow/2011-09-02/");
    }
};

private class ParseSite extends AsyncTask<String, Void, List<String>> {

    protected List<String> doInBackground(String... arg) {
        List<String> output = new ArrayList<String>();

        try
        {
            HtmlHelper hh = new HtmlHelper(new URL(arg[0]));
            List<TagNode> links = hh.getLinksByClass("title");

            for (Iterator<TagNode> iterator = links.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();)
            {
                TagNode divElement = (TagNode) iterator.next();
                output.add(divElement.getText().toString());
            }
            Log.d("dupa", "siteParsed");
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return output;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(List<String> output) {

        pd.dismiss();
        Log.d("dupa", "postExecute");
        ListView listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewData);
        //listview.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(StackParserActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1 , output));
        MyAdapter dupa = new MyAdapter(StackParserActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, R.id.movieTitle, output); 
        dupa.notifyDataSetChanged();
        listview.setAdapter(dupa);
        dupa.notifyDataSetChanged();

    }
}

private class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<string> {

    String[] tabObj;

    public MyAdapter(Context context, int resource, int textViewResourceId, List<String> output) {
        super(context, resource, textViewResourceId);
        tabObj = output.toArray(new String[]{});

        Log.d("dupa", tabObj[2].toString());
        notifyDataSetChanged();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.d("dupa", "!!!!getView");

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_layout,parent,false);
        TextView tv = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.movieTitle);         

        tv.setText(tabObj[position]);

        //Button buton1 = (Button) row.findViewById(R.id.buttonInfo);
        //Button button2 = (Button) row.findViewById(R.id.buttonReserve);

        return super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
    }
};
```

}

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Return `row` from `getView` method. Also remove the `notifyDatasetChanged()` from the `MyAdapter` constructor.

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Log.d("dupa", "!!!!getView");

    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_layout,parent,false);
    TextView tv = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.movieTitle);         

    tv.setText(tabObj[position]);

    //Button buton1 = (Button) row.findViewById(R.id.buttonInfo);
    //Button button2 = (Button) row.findViewById(R.id.buttonReserve);

    return row;
}
```

**EDIT :**
Try overriding `getCount` in adapter where you return the `size()` of `tabObj`

Comment: I changed the code as you suggested. Iam now returning row and I removed all notifyDatasetChanged(), but still nothing. getView methode doesnt lunch. Log.d("dupa", "!!!!getView"); doesnt output anything to Log :/

Comment: You should override `getCount` in adapter.

Comment: The edit was my problem (override getCount). I copied an adapter from another project but forgot to grab this method from the bottom.

Answer (score 1):

Since you set the adapter onPostExecute, there is no need to set notifyDataChanged in any of the places that you call it.

The reason that notifyDataChanged is used is to notify the adapter that has been set to a listview that the data have changed and you should update it. Hope this helps!

Comment: I suspected that, adding notifyDataChanged didn't help ... It was my act of desperation :/

Comment: Remove both from the onPostExecute and the constructor of the adapter. If it is still no working, do you get any error? Is the size of the list > 0 ?

Comment: It still doesnt work after removing all 'notifyDataChanged()'                           Log.d("dupa", tabObj[2].toString()); Shows in DDMS with correct data, so yes, list 'output' > 0 and array 'tabObj' is > 0.

Answer (score 0):

```
private class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<string> {

    String[] tabObj;

    public MyAdapter(Context context, int resource, int textViewResourceId, List<String> output) {
        super(context, resource, textViewResourceId);
        tabObj = output.toArray(new String[]{});
```

When we are creating a custom arrayadapter we must be using either

```
public ArrayAdapter (Context context, int textViewResourceId, T[] objects)

public ArrayAdapter (Context context, int resource, int textViewResourceId, T[] objects)

public ArrayAdapter (Context context, int textViewResourceId, List<T> objects)

public ArrayAdapter (Context context, int resource, int textViewResourceId, List<T> objects)
```

if we are not using above mention adapter, we need to override `getCount()` method.

In your case, 
`super(context, resource, textViewResourceId,output);`
will solve your problem.